# Заполнение списка данными из бд SQLite

Tags: c#, база-данных

Доброго времени суток, есть класс описывающий записи в бд:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public string Club { get; set; }
    public string ChallengeName { get; set; }
    public int Place { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfMedals { get; set; }
}
```

Необходимо на старте формы заполнить таблицу, вроде ничего сложного, но тут встал перед вопросом, т.к. записи состоят из 2 типов данных, именно `Int` и `String`, то таким образом я поступить не смогу?

```
private void LoadData()
{
    Connection.Connections();
    List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
    using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = Connection.ExecuteData($"SELECT * FROM List"))
    {
        if (rdr != null)
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Person n = new Person();
                Person[] L = new Person[] { rdr.GetInt32(0), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetString(2), rdr.GetString(3), rdr.GetInt32(4), rdr.GetInt32(5) };
                n.Id = L[0];
                n.FIO = L[1];
                n.Club = L[2];
                n.ChallengeName = L[3];
                n.Place = L[4];
                n.NumberOfMedals = L[5];
                list.Add(n);
            }
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Как корректно нужно объявить и заполнить список?

Comment: А чего так по старинке то? Entity Framework уже давно изобрели

Comment: Зачем нужен Person[] L ? И почему ты его инициализируешь не **Person**, а int и string? Может так :  Person n = new Person(){ Id = rdr.GetInt32(0)  ,... };

Comment: @Сергей, пока нужно так.